# How can I find all the records that has the same last four digits of social security number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I work for a university and I am given an assignment to do some testing on the logic that a developer has made changes to.

What I need:
I need a SQL Server query that looks into a Persons table and finds records that has the same last four digits of Social Security numbers.  In addition to that, I also want to see if these records (whose last four digits of SSN is the same) also has the same last name.

Here's what I have so far:
--I am pretty new to SQL so I am stuck to figure out how I can only compare last four digits of SSN and also find students who has the same last four digits of SSN and same last name.

```
SELECT t1.PersonsID, 
   t1.LastName, 
   t1.GovernmentID, 
   t2.PersonsID, 
   t2.LastName, 
   t2.GovernmentID
FROM Persons t1, Persons t2
WHERE t1.GovernmentID = t2.GovernmentID
AND t1.PersonsID <> t2.PersonsID
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

After looking at what Joe said I made another attempt:

```
  SELECT
  t1.cmn_personsID,
  t1.governmentID,
  t1.lastname,
  t2.cmn_personsID,
  t2.governmentID,
  t2.lastname,
  case when t1.LastName = t2.lastName then 1 else 0 end as SameLastName
  from
  CMN_Persons t1, cmn_persons t2 
  WHERE right(t1.GovernmentID, 4) = right(t2.GovernmentID, 4) 
  AND t1.cmn_PersonsID <> t2.cmn_PersonsID
```

This thing has been running for five minutes now.  when I tried using top 10, it didn't seem give me users with same last four digits of governmentID and who would have same last name.

Comment: SSN is your GovernmentId here?

Comment: Yes, The SSN is the GovernmentID.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GovernmentID is numeric?  If so then modulo will work.

```
SELECT t1.PersonsID, 
   t1.LastName, 
   t1.GovernmentID, 
   t2.PersonsID, 
   t2.LastName, 
   t2.GovernmentID,
   case when t1.LastName = t2.lastName then 1 else 0 end as SameLastName
FROM Persons t1, Persons t2
WHERE t1.GovernmentID % 10000 = t2.GovernmentID % 10000
AND t1.PersonsID ne t2.PersonsID
```

To answer part 2, you can add in a flag.

Comment: One note - `<>` is wrong, it is the min operator, `ne` is correct (or `^=` if you prefer that style).

Answer (score 1):

Try using GROUP BY and HAVING like this.

```
SELECT 
Z.PersonID,
Z.Last4,
Z.Cnt
LastName = (SELECT LastName FROM Persons WHERE PersonID = Z.PersonID) 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT t1.PersonsID, 
    t1.GovermentID % 10000 as Last4, 
    COUNT(*) as Cnt
    FROM Persons t1
    GROUP BY t1.GovermentID % 10000, PersonID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) Z
ORDER BY Last4
```

Comment: What is `top 100 percent` here for?

Comment: My bad. Not needed. I fixed it now.